# VideoPlayer crash if user plays multiple video video back to back, is this memory overload issue?

Tags: flutter

VideoPlayer crash if I play multiple videos back to back, I am using video_player & Chewie, I can play 5 to 6 times back to back video after that application got crash & It gives me error "Lost connection to the device."

Here is the version which I am using.

> video_player: ^0.7.0
>  chewie: ^0.9.7

Here is my code

```
VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(url);

chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
      autoInitialize: true,

});
```

Comment: Did you `dispose` the `videoPlayerController ` when done

Comment: Yes, I have tried, If I dispose, it shows me error video player controller is used after disposed, for your information In my requirement in one file only I need to play multiple videos.

Comment: It's probably a memory overload, I tried making a scrollable similar to Instagram auto playing video. And after several videos (maybe five) I got the same issue.

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was? How to solve it?

Comment: Yes @AkbarB it was resolved by disposing current videoPlayerController before starting new one, I have attached sample code below

VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(url);

now If I required to play another video in same screen then first I need to dispose this videoPlayerController first,

videoPlayerController.dispose();

then initialize another instance with same variable,

videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(anotherURL);

You can play multiple video in ListView also.

Let me know if any.

Comment: @NahimMakhani But if we scroll back to the previous video, it gives an error, because its controller is disposed! A common use case an app like tiktok!